# VBA looping though cells in a range

Tags: vba, excel, loops, foreach

I am working on a piece of code that will run through a sheet of data and check that said data is in the master sheet and if it is not found, it will add the data.

I was working on doing it via a `For Each Cell in range`. However, I am running into a issue that I cannot seem to find a work around for. This may just be me being slow and not finding it after working on some things for a few hours.

Here is what I have so far. I will spare the declarations.

The data looks something like this. On the Gold sheet I have
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4lzh.png)
On the other I have: 
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1gLj.png)

The code is meant to take sheet1 and see if any of those stock codes are missing from sheet2, and if they are missing to just notify the user.

```
Set xlsheet1 = Sheets("Gold")
Set xlsheet4 = Sheets("Working Sheet")

xlsheet1.Activate

xllr1 = xlsheet1.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
Set xlrange1 = xlsheet1.Range("B1:B" & xllr1)

With Range("A:Z")
```

> Given my data is dynamic, i use the following .find to find the column
>   with the stock codes.

```
    Set gs = .Find(what:="Symbol", After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    gcol = gs.Column
    fr1 = gs.Row + 1
End With

xlsheet4.Activate

xllr4 = xlsheet4.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Set xlrange4 = xlsheet4.Range("A1:A" & xllr3)
```

> this is where i encounter an issue. It works fine when the stock code matches. I was thinking of putting in a line saying if i = xllr1 and xlcell4.value <> cells(i, gcol) then etc... but it just doesn't seem to work.

```
xlsheet1.Activate
For i = fr1 To xllr1
    For Each xlcell4 In xlrange4
        If xlcell4.Value = Cells(i, gcol) Then
        Else
            MsgBox "did not find code " & Cells(i, gcol)
        End If
    Next xlcell4
Next i
```

I hope that makes sense and appreciate any help!

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a small snapshot of each sheet and what you expect the relationship between them to be. It's typically pretty challenging to just read a mess of VBA and visualize what is taking place in the worksheet(s).

Comment: declarations are important

Comment: Hi @PatJones , I will upload a mock up of the sheets to give more context. Thanks for the feedback.  I’ve only posted a snippet of a bigger macro, just didn’t want to clog up space.

Comment: @Manu221 according to your screen-shot, you have a **Typo**, you wrote `smybol` instead of `symbol`. Second, in both screen-shots the data is in column A, in your code you it;s in column B, so which one is it ?

Comment: @ShaiRado I can’t take an actual screenshot of the data since I do not have access to it at the moment. I just did a quick mock up of what the data would look like. The data in the actual sheet is in column B. The typing of symbol is just a typo.

Comment: @Manu221 OK, i'll update the code in my answer below, need 5 minutes

Comment: @Manu221 see edited code in my answer below, let me know if this works as you intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just dump the values that you're searching through into an array:

```
Dim xlwb As Workbook
Dim xlsheet1 As Worksheet
Dim xlsheet4 As Worksheet
Dim list As Range
Dim listLength As Integer
Dim arr1()

Set xlwb = ThisWorkbook
Set xlsheet4 = xlwb.Sheets("Working Sheet")

listLength = xlsheet4.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Set list = xlsheet4.Range("A1:A" & listLength)

ReDim arr1(listLength)
j = 0

For Each xlCell in list
    arr1(j) = xlCell
    j = j + 1
Next xlCell
```

Then search the array for each element:

```
Set xlsheet1 = xlwb.Sheets("Gold")
Set list = xlsheet1.Range("B1:B" & xlsheet1.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row)

For Each xlCell in list

    found = False

    For j = 0 To UBound(arr1)
        If arr1(j) = xlCell Then
            found = True
        EndIf
    Next j

    If Not found MsgBox "Element not found: " & xlCell

Next xlCell
```

It's just another possibility for how to do this!

Comment: Thank you! Didn't even cross my mind to do it via an array! Makes my life so much easier!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to trap the scenario where `Find` was unable to find a "match", by using `If Not gs Is nothning Then`.

Also, you have too many uses of unecessary `Activate` between our `Sheets`, this takes a long time to execute, instead use fully qualifed reference, by using `With` statements.

When looking to match values in 2 columns in 2 different worksheets, the fastest and "cleanest" way is to use one `For` loop and `Application.Match` function (see how it's implemented in the code below).

***Modified Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareStocks()

Dim xlsheet1 As Worksheet
Dim xlsheet4 As Worksheet
Dim gs As Range, xlrange1 As Range, xlrange4 As Range, C As Range
Dim xllr1 As Long, xllr4 As Long, gcol As Long, fr1 As Long
Dim i As Long

Set xlsheet1 = Sheets("Gold")
Set xlsheet4 = Sheets("Working Sheet")

With xlsheet1
    xllr1 = .Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
    Set xlrange1 = .Range("B1:B" & xllr1) ' set the Range of Stocks in "Gold" sheet
End With

With xlsheet4
    Set gs = .Cells.Find(what:="Symbol", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not gs Is Nothing Then  ' find was successful
        gcol = gs.Column
        fr1 = gs.Row + 1
    Else ' <-- Find failed to find a match >> raise an error message
        MsgBox "Unable to find Symbol", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' set the range of "Symbol"s in "Working Sheet"
    xllr4 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, gcol).End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in the column where "Symbol" was found
    Set xlrange4 = .Range(.Cells(1, gcol), .Cells(xllr4, gcol)) ' set the range where all "Symbol"s are located
End With

' ===== Comparing values in 2 columns in 2 worksheets could be achieved with one For loop, and one Application.Match =====
' loop through cells in Stock range in "Gold" sheet
For Each C In xlrange1
    If IsError(Application.Match(C.Value, xlrange4, 0)) Then ' if Match was unable to find a matching record in "Symbol" range in "Working Sheet"
        C.Offset(, 1).Value2 = "Stock not found in " & xlsheet4.Name & " sheet!" ' write an error message to the column on the right
'        MsgBox "did not find code " & .Cells(i, gcol)
    End If
Next C

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Shari, thanks for the feedback. I’m going to edit my original post so it makes more sense. I will also upload a mock-up of the data so that the question makes more sense.